# Form-group inside a form-horizontal is overstretching previous form-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 I have a very simple form inside a panel:

[image]

It's pretty simple but the "Post" button isn't lining up nicely.

That's the HTML behind the form:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">Say something...</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea class="form-control"
                    rows="5"
                    placeholder="What are you up to?"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-11 col-md-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

According to the Bootstrap documentation, .form-group behaves like .row when inside a .form-horizontal - therefore offsetting the button (col-md-offset-11) should place the button vertically aligned to the textarea.

This panel is loaded inside a row in another page:

```
<div class="container">
  ...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
      <div ui-view="quickPost"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
```

As .form-group behaves like a .row, it should work fine when inside a .row (it's fine to wrap rows inside rows).

As I'm not experienced with CSS and Bootstrap, I'm pretty sure it's a silly oversight from my part. Can anyone spot what mistake I've made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here isn't exactly with Bootstrap's grid system - it's actually because the size you've allocated for the Post button is simply too narrow. (It's in a `col-md-1` inside a `col-md-8`, so it only gets 1/12 * 8/12 = 5.5% of the maximum width of `.container` (1170px): ~65px, and that's not even taking into account 15px padding.)

As a result, the button (which can't break to a new line to remain inside the narrow column) will overflow out of the available space, resulting in the alignment appearing off.

You can solve this in a couple ways: you could allocate more space for the button by increasing the number of columns it can take up, then have the button expand to 100% width to touch the right edge [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/vXs13YtXqV):

```css
button {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- [...] -->
    <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </div>
<!-- [...] -->
```

Or, you can leverage Bootstrap's `pull-right` class to keep the button flush against the right side (at which point, the number of columns you specify won't matter since they won't have any effect) [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/voZOocso7z):

```html
<!-- [...] -->
    <div class="col-md-offset-11 col-md-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Post</button>
    </div>
<!-- [...] -->
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It sure helps - I didn't realize the width of a button was fixed - thought they were "flexible" - I mean they adapted to the width of the column. My mistake. I got it working using "pull-right" - thanks.